# Best way to add entities/models to shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

Shopify has products, collections and other entities that have a well established admin. I want to add several extra entities in order to expand that functionality.

For example, colours. Our products have colours, so we need to relate colours and products. This could be done naively with tags, but then we can't get a list of all the colours and people can make typos when tagging products.

If I were developing in another context, I would create a new table named "Colours" and then a many-to-many relation between the Products and Colours tables.

Is there someway to manage entities in a similar fashion inside shopify?

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a really easy way to do this. Go to settings -> Metafields in the Admin of your store. You can now make a definition like colors. So if your store is foobar, a metafield could be product.foobar.colours where foobar is simply a namespace.

Now you can go to any product in your store, and set a colour for it. It would likely make more sense to do this via a product variant though, as that is an actual SKU with inventory.

So you can now experiment with this. You can customize products now to your heart's content, all without using a cheesy third-party App. You get access to the values you set for colours right in your Theme templates now. So obviously if you set a colour Red for something, you can expose that to customers.

If you have even a little skill with Javascript, it is now super easy to also add dynamic behaviour based on the values you set, so that you could perhaps change colours as merchants change variants.

Note that in the past, it was usual to assign a variant option to be colour, and then set colours for variants that way. The Metafields way is likely more useful as a complement to this older method.

Sky is the limit. No need for external Apps or databases! Infinite customization at your fingertips!